# Built-in webcam on Asus laptop missing under imaging devices in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, webcam

My built-in webcam for U43JC Asus laptop (Windows 7 32 bit) did not work, saying

> The camera is being used by another program.

I searched on the net to solve the problem and the solution that seemed to be working was to remove `usb2.0 uvc 1.3m webcam` and restart the computer and the webcam will automatically re-install.

However, not only did the webcam not re-install automatically, but the webcam is still not working. Things have gotten only worse that now I'm missing the webcam under Imaging Devices. I even tried recovering Windows to the factory state, however, the webcam was still missing.

What can I do to restore my `usb2.0 uvc 1.3m webcam`?

Comment: Have you installed the latest drivers from the Asus website? http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/U43Jc/HelpDesk_Download/ -> select your OS -> scroll down to "Camera" -> at the bottom of this section shows "Camera driver". Alternatively: if you can find the camera hardware ID within Device manager then we can help identify the package required...

Answer (score 0):

i have faced same prob as you but with different model i can't get my webcam working on N43SL but i found a way to solve it ,i don,t know if it work on U series or not

1. If your u43 has an asus utility called express gate maybe it will work (or if available install it, it should be on the driver disc)
2. Shutdown your u43 and boot to Asus Express Gate (I have a dedicated button for it on n43)
3. Go to settings (a gear icon) in express gate and choose webcam calibration, it will force the webcam to turn on.
4. Go to your windows os by an icon in express gate and check the webcam in device manager, it worked for me